# Why does Turbo C++ 3.0 give "size of the type is unknown or zero" error for C programs?

Tags: c, turbo-c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct Node
{

};
int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

This simple code is saved with a file name **NODE.C** and this gives an error :

> ERROR NODE.C 5: Size of the type is unknown or zero

The code works fine if I change the extension from **NODE.C** to **NODE.CPP**
Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: Compiling it with Clang (a non-terrible/horrible/sucky compiler that isn't amazingly outdated) actually gives useful information: *warning: empty struct is a GNU extension [-Wgnu-empty-struct]*

Comment: You need at least one member in your struct.

Comment: [Here are some pictures of Turbo C++ 3.0 at work](http://tinyurl.com/oy4y6mc). I particularly like [this one](http://blog.bestsoftware4download.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/step8.jpg), with its "1990, 1992" copyright notice. For those of you keeping score at home, this software is _twenty-four years old_, and predates the actual C++ language (as we know it today, i.e. standardised) by eight.

Comment: @remyabel: Why doesn't adding one member such as **Node *next;** still solve the problem?
It gives a declaration missing error. What went wrong?

Comment: @Sidsec9: In C, `Node*` does not name a type.  You need `struct Node* next;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Empty structures are not legal in C.

From the C99 standard, the relevant grammar productions are:

[image]

Note that *struct-declaration-list* is not optional, and must always have at least one *struct-declaration*.

In contrast, here is the C++ grammar:

[image]

Note that *member-specification* is optional.

Also note that an empty `struct` in C++ will not have size zero.  The C language also requires that all objects have non-zero size; the error message you're seeing isn't exactly accurate (the error is correct, but the descriptive message is not).

Comment: For the C++ case, citing the grammar isn't really enough proof (what about semantic rules?), but this'll do I guess.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about ;) (The edit was some time before your reply, and almost immediately after it was originally posted, but I guess you missed it.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I didn't provide it as proof that empty structures are allowed in C++.  I'm pointing out the big difference in the grammar.

Comment: You are citing C99 standard. Are you aware this is very far future from where Turbo C comes from?

Comment: @fjf2002: If you have access to an older standard and its different, I will be glad to update the answer.  Meanwhile, I'm using the verbiage I have available.

Comment: @fjf2002 many things don't change from one standard to the next. My Annotated C Standard book isn't at hand right now, but it's from 1990 - I could check it later and verify that it's the same.

Comment: Please do not take my comment above too seriously. I just wanted to make fun of an outdated IDE. I should have used some emoticon. By the way, I learnt programming just with IDEs from that time, too. But that was over 15 years ago.

Answer (score 5):

Empty struct is a syntax error in C. The grammar of C language is written so that it prohibits empty structs.

But it is legal in C++ to use empty structs. Thats why .C extension is giving you an error

Comment: Can you provide any _evidence_ for your claims?

Comment: Yeah its written in C99 standard(ISO/IEC 9899:TC3) for programming language C.   You may refer this for surity..  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf     (page 101 & 102 - 6.7.2.1)   :-)

Comment: *sigh* Yes, _I_ know that! What I'm trying to get at is that that should be part of your answer, which in general are expected to contain evidence rather than simply assertions. Thanks!

Comment: Oh! okeyyy :-(   ...will keep this in mind next time :-)